# linking two sentences with a connoctor or integrating them into one sentence for calrity

Tags: phrases, commas, connotations, paraphrasing

In the below example, can anyone give suggestions on how to connect the two or integrate them into one sentence?

> I wrote my thesis on The Effectiveness of Health Education. I evaluated the evidence through a systematic review.

The best version I come up with is the following:

> I wrote my thesis on The Effectiveness of Health Education, evaluating the evidence through a systematic review.

Comment: There are many ways to connect sentences together, there isn't a "best" way.  They all have different nuances.  You've used a participle phrase to modify the first clause. If that is what you want, that is fine.  I would actually favour separate sentences with some kind of discourse marker rather than a single sentence.

Comment: On purely stylistic grounds, it's not obvious to me why you'd want to call attention to both the ***activity*** of writing the thesis and its ***content*** in the same utterance. Maybe just settle for *My thesis on The Effectiveness of Health Education [evaluates / evaluated] the evidence through a systematic review* - obviously if it's *your* thesis, we know you wrote it without needing to be told that.

Comment: @JamesK could you give an example of applicable discourse makers, please?